# Failing to generate ed25519-sk key pair | Key enrollment failed: unknown or unsupported key type

Tags: openssh, ssh-keygen, yubico, yubikey, openssh-for-windows

I am trying to generate `ed25519-sk` and `ecdsa-sk` keys using `ssh-keygen` on my Windows computer. I have OpenSSH `OpenSSH_for_Windows_8.6p1, LibreSSL 3.4.3` installed and Yubikey `Firmware version: 5.4.3`. But, when I do `ssh-keygen.exe -t ed25519-sk -C "hello@example.com"` I get below error

```
Generating public/private ed25519-sk key pair.
You may need to touch your authenticator to authorize key generation.
Key enrollment failed: unknown or unsupported key type
```

However, generating `ecdsa` key works fine.

Can anyone please let me know how generate `ed25519-sk` or `ecdsa-sk` keys to use with Yubikey and Gitlab?

Thanks in advance